# HTML5 video is not playing dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a HTML video. It's working fine when it's static but when I'm setting it dynamically then it's not working. What did I miss?

Note that this is working fine in the snippet but is not working on my local version - why?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var videoURl = 'https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/mov_bbb.mp4';
  $('video').find('source').attr('src', videoURl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video width="400" controls autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Check the console for errors/warnings. Browsers have very tight controls over what video content is allowed to autoplay, such as whether the sound of the video is on, and how much the user has interacted with the domain before the video content was loaded.

Comment: This code should be work on your local PC. please check your Jquery version your local PC. and also jQuery version should be bellow 2.2.4 to work on your code

Answer (score 3):

This issue is probably caused by the fact that the video's `src` attribute is not  correctly set when the HTML5 autoplay feature comes into effect. Not all browser clearly report this error though. As mentioned already, browsers are also generally much stricter about autplaying content nowadays. For example, check Chrome's updated [autoplay policies](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).

In order to make this cross-browser compatible, you could instead prepare the `source` element in the script, append it to the `video` element, and then trigger the video's `play()` function (see the snippet below).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var videoURL = "https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/mov_bbb.mp4";
   var source = $("<source>");
   source.attr("src", videoURL);
   source.attr("type", "video/mp4");
   $("video").append(source);
   $("video").get(0).play()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video width="400" controls></video>
```